# Update datapanel when the model is switched

Tags: javascript, events, autodesk-forge, dashboard, viewer

I have an application linked with my autodesk account and I also have a panel dashboard that load the data from the current model, the issue is that this panel isnt update when I choose another model into the hub.

Im trying to find the `Autodesk.viewing.EVENT` that can record this step but I couldnt. All of them have been tryed and whitout success...

`Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT`,

`Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT`,

`Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ADDED_EVENT`...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this working. Don't worry about events, it's working fine.
Here are my changes and additions:
PanelBarChart.js(same goes in piechart as well)

```
loadWithCustomProperty(property) {
    this.propertyToUse = property;
    this.chart.destroy();
    this.drawChart();
}
```

After creating list in dashboard.js, add the change event:

```
$('#'+_this._selectcontainer).change(function() {
        console.log($('#'+_this._selectcontainer+' option:selected').text())
        _this._panel.loadWithCustomProperty($('#'+_this._selectcontainer+' option:selected').text())            
    });
```

Here _this._selectcontainer is UUID, because you're adding multiple chards, so id needs to be unique.

Comment: Thanks varunpatil. 
I dont understand... What Do you mean with _this._selectcontainer? Do you refer to the when the "userhubs panel" is selected or changed?

Comment: it's id of the select html element.